# Should someone tell a Jewish doctor about a tattoo of G-d's name?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, shemos-sacred-names, tattoo

**Background:** I am not Jewish. [I have a tattoo containing G-d's name](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/23462/1257). I have been in the process of removing this tattoo using laser treatment. [There seems to be some disagreement on whether or not Jewish law would allow me to remove this tattoo since I am a gentile](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/23479/1257). The head doctor of the tattoo removal clinic *may be* Jewish, but does not see the patients personally and may actually have no knowledge of the specific tattoos being removed by her medical assistants (who handle all patient interaction).

**Question:** Should someone getting a tattoo of G-d's name removed make an attempt to talk about this with the doctor (for her sake), or is it irrelevant since she does not administer the treatments but merely authorizes them in ignorance (or is it perhaps better if she remains ignorant)?<sup>1</sup>

*I only ask about this hypothetical situation, as I know that if this personally affects anyone (especially a Jew), they should consult a competent halachic decisor.*

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>By ignorance, I only mean that she authorizes the treatments without knowing that they are being used to erase G-d's name—not that she is uneducated or unsophisticated.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

I agree, no need to tell the head doctor.

It's the assistant who's actually lasering it off. The head doctor is just arranging for paperwork, and what's more; if he wasn't around, someone else would do it. Jews are prohibited from *enabling* others to sin, and discouraged from *assisting* others to sin; they are not, however, prohibited from *enabling enablers*, which is what it sounds like here.

Comment: Furthermore, if the assistant isn't Jewish, she isn't even enabling a sin - there is no sin (of which I am aware) for a non-Jew to erase G-d's name.

Comment: @yEz Perhaps it's considered *abizrayhu* of *giduf*... (I think the gemara considers interpreting *nokeiv shem* in both ways.)