# Shemos Tattoos?

Tags: halacha, shemos-sacred-names, tattoo

Scenario: Ploni gets a tattoo which either has a shem or a passuk. He later either becomes a B"T or converts?

Question: What halachot govern this? Can he go to the bathroom? Does that area of skin need to be embalmed before interment?

Of course, if this becomes a practical matter (b"h it isn't for anyone I know) please consult your rav.

Comment: dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/23462/759 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/23479/759 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/33855/759

Comment: Why would the body part need to be embalmed? Isn't internment the way we normally dispose of shemot?

Comment: Yes, but we typically try to slow the destruction of a shem, at least in sta"m.

Comment: @DoubleAA, the other questions didn't answer the other portions of mine.